# How to configure CORS in API written in Play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework, cors

I'm having very strange problem with probably CORS filter. I have react app which sends request to app (written in play framework (Scala)), catch JSON response and shows it on the screen. Both apps are deployed in azure cloud via GitHub Actions.
Console shows error (translated):
 `"Same Origin Policy” doesn't let read data from "my_backend_app_here” (there is no header CORS "Access-Control-Allow-Origin”).`
And ok, it would be understandable but it's no matter if CORS in .conf file is disabled or enabled.
Below is my .conf file:

```
slick.dbs.default.profile="slick.jdbc.SQLiteProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.profile="slick.driver.SQLiteDriver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:sqlite:/ebiznes.sqlite"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC

play.evolutions.db.default.enabled=true
play.evolutions.db.default.autocommit=true
play.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=true


play.modules {
  # By default, Play will load any class called Module that is defined
  # in the root package (the "app" directory), or you can define them
  # explicitly below.
  # If there are any built-in modules that you want to disable, you can list them here
  #enabled += my.application.Module

  # If there are any built-in modules that you want to disable, you can list them here
  #disabled += ""
  enabled += "modules.SilhouetteModule"
}

play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"

play.filters.hosts {
  allowed = ["."]
}

play.filters.cors {
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
  allowedOrigins = null
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
  allowedHttpHeaders = null
  supportsCredentials = true
}

include "silhouette.conf"
```

As you can see I accept all the hosts and prefixes.

My react app fetch looks:

```
export function getProducts() {
    
    return fetch("https://my_back_app_name_here/products").then((response) => response.json())
}
```

But as I said - it has no matter how it looks like. Now there are no headers, or `no-cors` mode etc. Sometimes it gives me `404` error.

I tried to **disable** CORS at my backend, but  it doesn't work as well.

Help me, it's very awkward problem.

PS: My backend app works fine with front which is running on my **localhost**! And this is odd too.

Comment: Not adding the cors filter disable cors ... But anyway that can hardly be recommended

Comment: Whatever you do, never allow the `null` origin. Doing so is equivalent to throwing the Same-Origin Policy out the window.

Comment: @cchantep - it doesn't work (not adding the cors)